# Echo Tax Amount for all products in magento

Tags: php, magento

In magento, I want to echo the tax rate for each and every product in particular category in this way :

```
([{"id":"1","name":"Shirt","price":"45.00","tax":null}]);
```

**I used the following code:**

```
      public function ws_products($store_id, $service, $categoryid){

      $res=array();

      Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store_id); 

  $c_id = $categoryid;
  $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
  $category->load($c_id);
  $collection = $category->getProductCollection()->addStoreFilter($store_id);
  $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');


foreach ($collection as $_product) {
$res[] = array(
  "id" => $_product->getId(),
  "name" => $_product->getName(),
  "price" => number_format($_product->getPrice(),2),
  "tax" => Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('tax_amount'),

                           ); 
   } 
   return($res); 
}
```

WHEN I AM USING

```
"tax" => Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('tax_amount'),
```

I AM GETTING TAX AS NULL.

Please kindly help me.

Comment: Are you getting all other fields such as id,name,price ?

Comment: YES, I am getting all other fields.

Comment: When i am selecting any product in ADD CART in forntend, the tax amount of that particular product is showing for all the products. LIKE THIS: ([{"id":"1","name":"Shirt","price":"45.00","tax":2.5000}]);      ([{"id":"2","name":"Sarees","price":"50.00","tax":2.5000}]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get tax by using product model -

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
$taxClassId = $product->getData("tax_class_id");
$taxClasses = Mage::helper("core")->jsonDecode(Mage::helper("tax")->getAllRatesByProductClass());
$taxRate = $taxClasses["value_".$taxClassId];
```

Now use, `$taxRate` as value of "tax" in the array.

```
"tax" => $taxRate,
```

Comment: Where you have applied your tax rules. Is it coming from Sales->Tax ?

Comment: yes, you want that options in same array '$res' above code ?
You have to post new question on this.

Comment: yes.it is not necessary to be in same array.i just need the custom option values either in same or in different array.i have posted it as another question.please kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

**THIS IS THE WORKING CODE,IT MIGHT BE HELPFUL TO OTHERS.**

```
 public function ws_products($store_id, $service, $categoryid) 
 {
  $res=array();
  Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store_id); 
  $c_id = $categoryid;
  $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
  $category->load($c_id);
  $collection = $category->getProductCollection()->addStoreFilter($store_id);
  $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

  foreach ($collection as $_product) 
   {

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
    $taxClassId = $product->getData("tax_class_id");
    $taxClasses = Mage::helper("core")->jsonDecode(Mage::helper("tax"->getAllRatesByProductClass());
    $taxRate = $taxClasses["value_".$taxClassId];
    $a = (($taxRate)/100) *  ($_product->getPrice());

                  $res[] = array(
                           "id" => $_product->getId(),
                           "name" => $_product->getName(),
                           "imageurl" => Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB).'/media/catalog/product'.$_product->getImage(),
                           "sku" => $_product->getSku(),
                           "spclprice" => number_format($_product->getSpecialprice(),2),
                           "price" => number_format($_product->getPrice(),2),
                           "tax" => number_format($a,2),
                           "created_date" => $_product->getCreatedAt(),
                           "is_in_stock" => $_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock(),
                           "stock_quantity" => Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product->getId())->getQty()
                           ); 
 } 
   return($res); 
  }
```